# Regex not to allow double underscores

Tags: regex

Trying to apply regex for not allowing a string with double underscores

```
 [a-z][a-z0-9_-]+[^__]
```

but its failing in many cases like:

```
ab_      doesn't matches whereas it should
ab__c_   matches whereas it shouldn't.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`[^__]` matches one character that is *not* underscore. To ***assert*** that your string doesn't have two consecutive underscores, you could use a [*negative lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!.*__.*)[a-z][a-z0-9_-]+$
```

The lookaround asserts that your string **does not** have two consecutive underscores `(?!.*__.*)`, and then matches your required string if the assertion does not fail -- `[a-z][a-z0-9_-]+`.

Comment: Nice answer; just one correction: `[^__]` matches /one/ character that's not an underscore.  May I edit your post to fix this typo?

Comment: @ron.rothman: You're very right indeed. Feel free to edit it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

the `[^]` syntax defines a **set** of characters so that it matches a character not present in this set

if you want to match two characters that are not underscores you can use `[^_]{2}`

but if you really want to check if a string has two underscores, you better search for two underscores and negate the result

for example in perl: `"ab_" !~ /__/`

Answer (score 1):

in perl it would be:

```
    if($a =~ /__/){
    } else{
    }
```

which means if string a contains "__" do something, if not do something else. Of course there is many ways how to beutify such code