# Regex to include single but exclude double hyphen

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to get a regex where words with single hyphens are counted as one, but those double hyphens are counted as two. Currently, this is what I have:

```
/\b([a-zA-Z0-9’'-])+\b/
```

What do I need to change to make this work?

Edit:
To clarify, I'm using this regex to count words.

Example:
single-dash (1 word)
double--dash (2 words)

I have tried to include a negative lookahead as suggested, but now it's igoring all words before the double dash ([link](http://regexr.com/3dq54))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384555/regex-not-to-allow-double-underscores could be a dupe but not too many answers over there

Comment: What do you mean by “counted as two”? Is “naïve” a word? Is “наивный” a word?

Comment: I'd rewrite it into a more restrictive regex: `[’']?\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+([’'-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\b[’']?`, though I'm not sure if it is what you want.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some examples of input and the output you want? Also, your question should include more than just your RegExp. How are you "counting" the words?

Comment: Further to @Jordan's comment, you need to be precise in your statement of the question, and avoid assumptions about the approach that should be taken to answer it. You've assumed a single regex should be used, but that's not the only option.  I believe your question is how words defined in a particular way should be counted. If so, you should express your question in those terms. When you show your attempt at a solution you need something like `str.scan(regex).size`, not just `regex`. (cont.)...

Comment: ...Lastly, an  example string and desired word count would be helpful. Assign the string to a variable (e.g., `str = "..."`) so readers can refer to the variable in answers and comments without having to define it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming English alphabet, and that there can only be at most one symbol (any of `[’'-]`) between substring of alphanumeric characters, and that there can only be at most one of those symbol at the beginning and the end of a "word" ("word" as defined in the question).

```
[’']?\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[’'-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\b[’']?
```

Test cases:

```
"Us and Them"’s inclusion on the album The Dark Side of the Moon
You Am I’s latest CD
The 69’ers’ drummer, Tom Callaghan (only the second apostrophe is possessive)
His ’n’ Hers’ first track is called "Joyriders".[18]
Was She's success greater, or King Solomon’s Mines's?
Rock 'n' Roll
’bout for about, ’less for unless, ’twas for it was
’70s for 1970s 
You-Know-Who
the fo’c’s’le’s timbers
Three-hundred-year-old trees are an indeterminate number of trees that are each aged 300 years.
syl-la-bi-fi-ca-tion
double--hyphen
```

[**Demo at Rubular**](http://rubular.com/r/881MnbR4JX)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `\b` is not a good option, positions before/after hyphen are matched as `\b` themselves.

The regexp below works for the whole string: `(-(?!-))` negative lookahead matches only single hyphen.

```
/\A(['’\p{Alnum}]|(-(?!-)))+\z/
```

Whether you still need to have a regexp, that matches “words” (whatever it means) with one hyphen only, one should explicitly specify symbols, that are “word breakers”:

```
re = /(?<![\p{Alnum}'’-])((['’\p{Alnum}]|(-(?!-)))+)(?![\p{Alnum}'’-])/ 
'goo goo-bar goo--bar, goo-bar--baz'.scan(re).map &:first
#⇒ ["goo", "goo-bar"]
```

Comment: Do you think you could break down your regexes, and explain the parts?

Comment: I already explained the only non-obvious part (negative lookahead) and the first example is kinda part of the second one.

Comment: Ok. Regexes always look like gibberish to me anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the objective is to count words, where those containing two successive hypens are to be counted as two words. Rather than attempting to do everything in a single regex, I've merely replaced all instances of two or more consecutive hyphens with a space, thereby splitting the word into two words, and then just counted the words.

```
def count_words(str)
  str.gsub(/-{2,}/, ' ').scan(/[a-zA-Z0-9’'-]+/).size
end
```

I'll use part of @nhahtdh's test string for demonstration.

```
str =<<BITTER_END
"Us and Them"’s inclusion on the album The Dark Side of the Moon
You Am I’s latest CD
The 69’ers’ drummer, Tom Callaghan (only the second apostrophe is possessive)
His ’n’ Hers’ first track is called "Joyriders".[18]
Was She's success greater, or King Solomon’s Mines's?
Rock 'n' Roll
’bout for about, ’less for unless, ’twas for it was
’70s for 1970s
BITTER_END
```

```
  #=> "\"Us and Them\"’s inclusion on the album The Dark Side of the Moon\nYou Am   I’s latest CD\nThe 69’ers’ drummer, Tom Callaghan (only the second apostrophe is possessive)\nHis ’n’ Hers’ first track is called \"Joyriders\".[18]\nWas She's success greater, or King Solomon’s Mines's?\nRock 'n' Roll\n’bout for about, ’less for unless, ’twas for it was\n’70s for 1970s\n"
```

```
count_words(str) #=> 63
```

@nhahtdh and @mudasobwa get the same count (63) for `str` above.