# Prevent double underscore(_) using regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Regex for Email validation to validate  email ids like:

- abc__xyz@gmail.com
- abc..xyz@gmail.com
- abc@gmail.com99

Last 2 email format working fine for me but not for first one(not two consecutive underscore should come). 
Currently I am using:

```
var regex = /^[a-z0-9!$%*=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!$%*=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel)$/i;
```

Can anyone  please help me in prevent two consecutive underscore(_) ?

Comment: What's wrong with two consecutive underscores in an email address?

Comment: It is valid email when you use two consecutive underscores in email, Your reg ex is actually working fine, until and unless you are not doing something other than regular email validation.

Comment: @Pointy nothing wrong but  as per requirement i have to prevent consecutive underscore.

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384555/regex-not-to-allow-double-underscores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var regex = /^(?!.*__.*)[a-z0-9!$%*=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!$%*=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|asia|biz|cat|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel)$/i;
```

Source: [Regex not to allow double underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384555/regex-not-to-allow-double-underscores)